# break when any method of class is invoked

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm using Eclipse to debug a Java class. I want the debugger to break any time a public method of class X is invoked. However, this class has a lot public methods, so I'd prefer not to have to do this manually. Does Eclipse provide a simple way to do this?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not completely automatically, but:

1. Select all methods in the Outline view
2. Right click and choose "Toggle method breakpoint"

This will add breakpoints to all selected methods.